# Do I still need to use 'select ... for update' in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

If two clients update same record, in php, I will use `select...for update`.

Since node.js is single thread, do I also need to use `select...for update` in node.js?

DB is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one client with a single thread accessing the mysql table then you don't need lock the rows using select...for update.

So if the only thing accessing the mysql database is a single nodejs client there's no need to lock the rows. If there's a chance another client might try to access the rows simultaneously then you should lock them.